# Input boxes that expand onClick with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I have this `input[type="text"]` on my page on which I've been working on for some time. What I wanna do is to create an effect of it expanding, when the user clicks in it. Also, I want it to return to its normal width when the mouse goes out.

My code so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 250; i < 501; i++) {
      $(this).css("width", (i.toString + "px"))
    }
  })
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

I've used the `.click()` jQuery function here. Are there any other functions which can detect a cursor in an element? Something like `.cursorIn()`, if it exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transition: width ease 1s` (and use the `:hover` psuedo element if you want)

See demo below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").click(function() {
    $(this).css("width", "500px")
  })
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: width ease 1s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
```

With pure CSS you can use the `focus` psuedo element like this:

```css
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: width ease 1s;
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  width : 500px;
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Argg... Alright people listen up. I want the box to expand when ***clicked*** and **not when hovered**!

Comment: @AravindSuresh also added in a *pure CSS* solution using `focus` psuedo element... check it out and let me know your thoughts....

Comment: I liked that CSS Idea really well. *Merci encore*!

Answer (score 2):

There is CSS solution to it, using `transition` with `toggling` class `.on("click")`: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prnfuv0t/2/)

**CSS**

```
input[type="text"] {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-style: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 250px;
  transition: width .3s linear;
  -webkit-transition: width .3s linear;
}
.expand {
  width:500px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" />
```

**jQuery**

```
$("input[type='text']").on("click", function(e){
  $(this).toggleClass("expand");
}
```

Comment: Actually, I wanted the `input` to expand when it was *clicked*, not hovered.

Comment: There are 3 ways to interpret 'put cursor in it' in code world: mouseenter, mouseover and click. But be my guest, I'm editing my answer now :)

Comment: @wscourge i answered on mouseenter before :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [mouseenter](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) or [hover](https://api.jquery.com/hover/)

```
 //Mouseenter
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $("input").on("mouseenter",function() {
    var i;
    for (i = 250; i < 501; i++) {
      $(this).css("width", (i.toString + "px"))
    }
  });
 });


 //Hover
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("input").hover(function() {
        var i;
        for (i = 250; i < 501; i++) {
          $(this).css("width", (i.toString + "px"))
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: It has to expand when **clicked**, not when *hovered*.